# WooCommerce 4.0.1 order emails not formatting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Since upgrade to WC 4.0.1 the order emails formatting is not correct. Before, on WC 3.x, the formatting of the emails **was** correct.

Words with spaces between letters, inline HTML, different font and font-size etc. (see screenshots)

Made an exact copy of the shop on hostingcompany A, with Duplicator and installed it on a different hostingcompany (hostingcompany B). Order emails was formatting correctly.
Installed the same copy on a subdomain in hostingcompany A. Order emails are not formatted correctly.

Installed a mail-log plugin (WP mail log) to capture all emails. View in HTML is correct.

What i've tried:
- Deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce (make order in backend)
- Reinstall WooCommerce plugin
- Emails in plain text have the same problem (same as Multipart)
- Checked charset op de webshop (utf-8). same as before the upgrade.
- Use the standard email templates of WC.

Whatever I try on hostingcompany A, the order emails are not formatting correctly. in WC 3.X and before we did not had this problem.

Please see attached screenshot to explain in more detail what is going on. I have attached 2 screenshots. One screenshot with the wrong formatting and one screenshot with the correct formatting.

[image: Wrong formatting of order email]

[image: Good formatting of order email]

Answer (score 0):

Problem found. Spamfilter ISP.